# rich:fileupload problem with filter

Tags: jsf, richfaces, servlet-filters

hi i have a problem with rich fileupload , i have a website with some discussion group with restricted access.

for allow that i use a filter that scan the request and redirect you if you have no access. the problem is using rich:fileupload with this:

www.XXXXXX.com/faces/file.jsp?id=2 for example
at this time i can access to the fileupload form

```
<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadManager.listener}"
id="upload" immediateUpload="true"> </rich:fileUpload>
```

i have tried also to insert something like this into the fileUpload tags

```
<a4j:actionparam name="id" value="#{group.id}" 
assignTo="#{fileUploadManager.idgruppo}"></a4j:actionparam>
```

at this time i have not problem with filter but the listener doesn't work, anyone can help me , i have to use richfaces not something else because this is an assignment for university pourpose.

i have allowed flash but the problem persist  this is the server log

```
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:Initializing filter
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:doFilter()
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:DoBeforeProcessing
INFO: idgroup:23

INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:DoAfterProcessing
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:doFilter()
INFO: PWC1412: WebModule[/PW_socialnetworkRich] ServletContext.log():FileFilter:DoBeforeProcessing
INFO: idgroup:null
INFO: Listener:
INFO: Name of the uploaded file
GRAVE: The log message is null.
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'fk_group' at row 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is using the attribute `allowFlash` set to "true". Activating the embedded Flash module you can upload files to the sever without using Ajax request avoiding your filter.